# iOS/JavaScript - How to select text in div in UIWebView use JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview

I load my test.html in `UIWebView`:

test.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #btn {
                width:50px;
                height:150px;
                background: gray;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">The text I want to select.</div>
        <div id="btn" onclick="selectMain()"></div>
    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
/**
 The function to select #main's text
 */
function selectMain() {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById("main"));
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    console.log(range);
}
</script>
```

It's works fine on PC browser, but not select text of `#main` div in `UIWebView` when I click `#btn` and the `selectMain` function was actually called.

Comment: add innerHTML like document.getElementById("main").innerHTML

Comment: @lalithkumar @lalithkumar You mean `range.selectNode(document.getElementById("main").innerHTML)`? selectNode's first parameter is the type of 'Node'.

Comment: where you are selecting the text of div#main?

Comment: @lalithkumar use the `selectMain` function